# Cannot insert Integer data into MySQL, it inserts as a 0

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**Overview:**

I have a module on my site that allows the user to import .txt files (with data separated by semicolons and escaped by newlines) which then I grab and do a `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` with to insert on the database. The script works, but not as intended. Possible points of interest:

- Text file is encoded as `UTF-16LE`
- Database/table default charset is `utf8`, InnoDB engine.

**The issue:**

The script only inserts the correct data when all columns on the database are set to `VARCHAR`. If I try to change the ones that are meant to contain numbers to `INT`, the script inserts a 0 (zero) where the data should be.

**Debug attempts:**

Have tried inserting random hardcoded data on the script and it **does work**. This led me to believe the issue laid on file encoding.

I've tried manipulating the text file's encoding but that doesn't seem to help though.

Have also tried converting the file to .csv, .xlsx (using a different script with `PhpSpreadsheet`) but it yields the same results.

**Code:**

PHP:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "databse";
$file = str_replace("\\", "\\\\", $_FILES["polizas"]["tmp_name"]);
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES["polizas"]["tmp_name"])) {
    try {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true));
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $status = $pdo->exec(
            "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" . $file . "'
                IGNORE
                INTO TABLE `polizas`
                FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
                LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                IGNORE 1 LINES
                (`seccion`, `propuesta`, `poliza`, `endoso`, `tipo_endoso`, `desc_tipo_endoso`, `pol_que_renueva`, `iva_cond`, `tipo_doc`, `nro_doc`, `apellido`, `domicilio`, `cod_postal`, `telefono`, `localidad`, `provincia`, `fecha_emision`, `fecha_inicio`, `fecha_vcto`, `canal_pago`, `desc_canal_pago`, `origen`, `productor`, `organizador`, `moneda`, `item`, `marca`, `modelo`, `cero_Km`, `motor`, `chasis`, `patente`, `tipo_carroceria`, `desc_tipo_carroceria`, `cobertura`, `desc_cobertura`, `cod_acc1`, `desc_acc1`, `valor_acc1`, `cod_acc2`, `desc_acc2`, `valor_acc2`, `cod_acc3`, `desc_acc3`, `valor_acc3`, `cod_acc4`, `desc_acc4`, `valor_acc4`, `suma_aseg`, `prima`, `recarg`, `der_emision`, `sellos`, `imp_tasas`, `otros`, `bonif`, `iva`, `adminis_financ`, `premio`, `cant_cuotas`, `ajuste`, `tipo_vehiculo`, `desc_tipo_vehiculo`, `codigo_uso`, `descripcion_uso`, `ano_fab`, `nro_prestamo`, `vcto_cuota1`, `vcto_prestamo`, `tipo_prestamo`, `tipo_operacion`, `seccion_pol_paquete`, `poliza_pol_paquete`)"
        );
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Text file example:

```
seccion;propuesta;poliza;endoso;tipo endoso;desc tipo endoso;pol que renueva;iva;tipo doc;nro doc;apellido;domicilio;cod postal;telefono;localidad;provincia;fecha emision;fecha inicio;fecha vcto;canal pago;desc canal pago;origen;productor;organizador;moneda;item;marca;modelo;cero Km;motor;chasis;patente;tipo carroceria;desc tipo carroceria;cobertura;desc cobertura;cod acc1;desc acc1;valor acc1;cod acc2;desc acc2;valor acc2;cod acc3;desc acc3;valor acc3;cod acc4;desc acc4;valor acc4;suma aseg;prima;recarg;der emision;sellos;imp tasas;otrod;bonif;iva;adminis financ;premio;cant cuotas;ajuste;tipo vehiculo;desc tipo vehiculo;codigo uso;descripcion uso;año fab;nro prestamo;vcto cuota1;vcto prestamo;tipo prestamo;tipo operacion;seccion pol.paquete; poliza pol.paquete; 
4;0;894606;707641;65;Anul a Prorrata;0000000;IN;DNI;25035153;BLANCO ALEJANDRO DANIEL;B JARDIN MZA F CASA 9;05570;;SAN MARTIN;13;01/11/2018;27/09/2018;03/11/2018;08;Cobranza Normal;DC;0052000001;00520;0;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;-0,00;-1082,25;-0,00;-0,00;-0,00;-25,40;-17,32;-0,00;-242,42;-72,12;-1439,51;1;;0;NO DEFINIDO;0;NO DEFINIDO;0000;;;;;2;;;
4;2874759;945239;3;29;Refacturacion;0000000;CF;DNI;35210070;GENEM KEVIN DANILO;UNION 00;05596;263154279978;SANTA ROSA;13;01/11/2018;01/11/2018;01/12/2018;04;SO-Sobre;WEB;0012900077;00129;0;1;12340;CHEVROLET CORSA 1.4 4 P GL    L/09 (CLASSIC);N;T85032983;8AGSB19Y0AR169362;IRW910;1;SEDAN;C2;R.C. C/LTE. PERD.TOTAL X ACC. Y TOT.Y PARC X INC Y/O ROBO O HURTO;0;;0,00;0;;0,00;0;;0,00;0;;0,00;134000,00;524,11;0,00;0,00;8,33;12,22;0,00;0,00;116,65;31,36;692,67;1;20,00;1;AUTOMOVIL;101;AUTOS Y JEEPS NACIONALES O ASIMILAD;2010;;;;;1;;;
4;0;1001592;0;1;Poliza Nueva;0000000;CF;DNI;23649998;SILVA FELIX ALBERTO;CALLE LOS CHARABONES SN MONTEC;05570;263154320848;GENERAL SAN MAR;13;01/11/2018;01/11/2018;01/12/2018;08;Cobranza Normal;DC;0012900094;00129;0;1;17148;FIAT UNO S   1.4 3 PTAS (PREMIO);N;159A20388401620;8AP146000V841944;BQF655;1;SEDAN;A0;RESPONSABILIDAD CIVIL SOLAMENTE;0;;0,00;0;;0,00;0;;0,00;0;;0,00;0,00;365,94;0,00;0,00;5,78;8,48;0,00;0,00;80,98;19,66;480,84;1;0,00;1;AUTOMOVIL;204;AUTOS Y JEEPS NACIONALES GRUPO "B";1997;;;;;1;;;
4;2700189;904933;5;29;Refacturacion;0000000;CF;DNI;16330735;BOER CARLOS EDGARDO;SOLER 116;05570;;SAN MARTIN;13;01/11/2018;01/11/2018;01/12/2018;07;PF-Pago Facil;WEB;0012900005;00129;0;1;36167;RENAULT R 19 RE   4 PTAS AA;N;AB32015;841L53;BSB411;1;SEDAN;A0;RESPONSABILIDAD CIVIL SOLAMENTE;0;;0,00;0;;0,00;0;;0,00;0;;0,00;0,00;357,59;0,00;0,00;5,65;8,28;0,00;0,00;79,07;18,91;469,50;1;0,00;1;AUTOMOVIL;101;AUTOS Y JEEPS NACIONALES O ASIMILAD;1998;;;;;1;;;
4;0;1001622;0;1;Poliza Nueva;0000000;CF;DNI;33438471;MARRELLO DANIEL ALEXANDER;BOLIVIA 864 V*DEL CARMEN;05400;;SAN JUAN;18;01/11/2018;01/11/2018;01/05/2019;08;Cobranza Normal;DC;0065600001;00656;0;1;36327;RENAULT MEGANE F/2 RT  5 P.;N;AC39650;8A1BA0N25XL000059;COJ834;1;SEDAN;A0;RESPONSABILIDAD CIVIL SOLAMENTE;0;;0,00;0;;0,00;0;;0,00;0;;0,00;0,00;2176,88;0,00;0,00;70,00;50,46;0,00;0,00;481,63;116,60;2895,57;6;0,00;1;AUTOMOVIL;101;AUTOS Y JEEPS NACIONALES O ASIMILAD;1999;;;;;1;;;
4;0;1001702;0;2;Renovacion;0888568;CF;DNI;16076990;CHUMACERO ROBERTO;B LIBERTAD MF C6;05509;;UGARTECHE;13;01/11/2018;07/11/2018;07/12/2018;08;Cobranza Normal;DC;0045700007;00457;0;1;75055;MERCEDES BENZ C L 1620-45 M96;N;377983I04II688;9BM695016WB188117;DCQ882;35;*;A0;RESPONSABILIDAD CIVIL SOLAMENTE;0;;0,00;0;;0,00;0;;0,00;0;;0,00;0,00;614,99;0,00;0,00;9,80;14,37;0,00;0,00;137,14;38,08;814,38;1;0,00;6;CAMION;6132;CAMIONES HASTA 10 TON LIMITE REGION;1999;;;;;1;;;
4;3029886;985020;1;29;Refacturacion;0000000;CF;DNI;8456054;ROMERO VICTOR RAMON;BARRIO AMIGORENA SECTOR UNO 11;05539;2614470347;LAS HERAS;13;01/11/2018;01/11/2018;01/12/2018;;;WEB;0045700001;00457;0;1;12053;CHEVROLET CORSA 1.6 3 P GL AA DH   (CLASSIC);N;B16NE31045708;9BGSE08NVTC606100;BBM021;1;SEDAN;B0;RESP.CIVIL ROBO,HURTO E INCENDIO TOTAL-DAÑO TOTAL POR ACCIDENTE;25;EQUIPO DE GNC       ;6000,00;0;;0,00;0;;0,00;0;;0,00;120450,00;444,65;0,00;0,00;7,05;10,34;0,00;0,00;98,73;25,48;586,25;1;20,00;1;AUTOMOVIL;101;AUTOS Y JEEPS NACIONALES O ASIMILAD;1997;;;;;1;;;
4;2797244;926680;4;29;Refacturacion;0000000;CF;DNI;6717389;LLANOS JOSE ESTEBAN;HILARIO CUADROS S/N;05533;;LAVALLE;13;01/11/2018;01/11/2018;01/12/2018;07;PF-Pago Facil;WEB;0012900026;00129;0;1;18139;FORD F-100 LUJO D;N;DNLB42173;KA13MY37569;WXY691;6;ABIERTA;A0;RESPONSABILIDAD CIVIL SOLAMENTE;0;;0,00;0;;0,00;0;;0,00;0;;0,00;0,00;355,78;0,00;0,00;5,62;8,24;0,00;0,00;78,68;18,91;467,23;1;0,00;4;PICK UP;1317;PICK UP FAMILIAR;1972;;;;;1;;;
```

MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE `polizas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_carga` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `seccion` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `propuesta` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `poliza` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `endoso` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo_endoso` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `desc_tipo_endoso` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pol_que_renueva` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `iva_cond` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo_doc` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nro_doc` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `apellido` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `domicilio` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cod_postal` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `telefono` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `localidad` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `provincia` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_emision` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_inicio` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_vcto` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `canal_pago` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `desc_canal_pago` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `origen` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `productor` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `organizador` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `moneda` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `marca` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modelo` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cero_Km` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `motor` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `chasis` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `patente` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo_carroceria` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `desc_tipo_carroceria` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cobertura` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `desc_cobertura` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cod_acc1` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `desc_acc1` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valor_acc1` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cod_acc2` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `desc_acc2` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valor_acc2` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cod_acc3` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `desc_acc3` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valor_acc3` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cod_acc4` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `desc_acc4` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valor_acc4` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `suma_aseg` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prima` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `recarg` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `der_emision` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sellos` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imp_tasas` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `otros` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bonif` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `iva` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `adminis_financ` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `premio` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cant_cuotas` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ajuste` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo_vehiculo` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `desc_tipo_vehiculo` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `codigo_uso` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `descripcion_uso` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ano_fab` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nro_prestamo` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vcto_cuota1` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vcto_prestamo` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo_prestamo` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo_operacion` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `seccion_pol_paquete` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `poliza_pol_paquete` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_pago` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cobrada` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


ALTER TABLE `polizas`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `poliza` (`poliza`,`endoso`);


ALTER TABLE `polizas`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Notes: I'm using other scripts to insert dates and modify the tinyInt column on the table, these are irrelevant to the issue as far as I understand and can probably be ignored.

Also, I'm aware that both the length of most columns is very generic and the amount of columns is unnecesarily large. I'll work on the first point as soon as this is solved, and as for the second, the client has requested the table to be exactly as is right now. I'll see about ways to optimize it without compromising the requested structure, though if you have any suggestions feel free to share!

Edit: this is what I did to switch the data's encoding, it didn't change the result.

```
$fn = fopen($_FILES["polizas"]["tmp_name"], "r");
$result = fgets($fn);
$encoded = mb_convert_encoding($result, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16LE');
```

Comment: `int(11)` is useless, its just the same to `int`

Comment: Didn't know about that, thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: I would guess your character data is getting extra nuls that you aren't seeing; check the length.  While the unexpected nuls in the input for numbers make them 0. Note that https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html says "It is not possible to load data files that use the ucs2, utf16, utf16le, or utf32 character set.".   So encode the file in utf8 (and add a character set parameter to your load data statement) or ASCII (if there are in fact only ASCII chars)

Comment: Personally, I would be using `fgetcsv` and doing the inserts from my PHP code.

Comment: @ysth I've already tried changing the data to UTF-8 without success, see my edit. Is it possible I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: @miken32 I'll try fgetcsv and see if that yields any different results, thanks.

Comment: I don't know enough php to say if you are doing it wrong.  if you make a single line test file with just ASCII data (_not_ in UTF16/UCS2) and try it, does it work?

Comment: @ysth it does, I've tried doing that on a hand made text file and it goes through with no issues.

Comment: then you need to figure out how to convert your file from utf16le to utf8 in php, and all should be good, assuming you have no non-ascii characters or your character_set_database variable is utf8mb4 or you add `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` before FIELDS

Answer (score 0):

when you omit `ENCLOSED BY '"'` then all fields are enclosed and treated as strings. You must have fields that are enclosed by "" and others not and you must specify : `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'` because else all are treated as enclosed

```
$status = $pdo->exec(
            "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" . $file . "'
                IGNORE
                INTO TABLE `polizas`
                FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
                OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
                LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                IGNORE 1 LINES
                (`seccion`, `propuesta`, `poliza`, `endoso`, `tipo_endoso`, `desc_tipo_endoso`, `pol_que_renueva`, `iva_cond`, `tipo_doc`, `nro_doc`, `apellido`, `domicilio`, `cod_postal`, `telefono`, `localidad`, `provincia`, `fecha_emision`, `fecha_inicio`, `fecha_vcto`, `canal_pago`, `desc_canal_pago`, `origen`, `productor`, `organizador`, `moneda`, `item`, `marca`, `modelo`, `cero_Km`, `motor`, `chasis`, `patente`, `tipo_carroceria`, `desc_tipo_carroceria`, `cobertura`, `desc_cobertura`, `cod_acc1`, `desc_acc1`, `valor_acc1`, `cod_acc2`, `desc_acc2`, `valor_acc2`, `cod_acc3`, `desc_acc3`, `valor_acc3`, `cod_acc4`, `desc_acc4`, `valor_acc4`, `suma_aseg`, `prima`, `recarg`, `der_emision`, `sellos`, `imp_tasas`, `otros`, `bonif`, `iva`, `adminis_financ`, `premio`, `cant_cuotas`, `ajuste`, `tipo_vehiculo`, `desc_tipo_vehiculo`, `codigo_uso`, `descripcion_uso`, `ano_fab`, `nro_prestamo`, `vcto_cuota1`, `vcto_prestamo`, `tipo_prestamo`, `tipo_operacion`, `seccion_pol_paquete`, `poliza_pol_paquete`)"
        );
```

and then your data must be like this(having fields enclosed by ")

```
4;0;894606;707641;65;"Anul a Prorrata";0000000;"IN";"DNI";25035153;"BLANCO ALEJANDRO DANIEL";"B JARDIN MZA F CASA 9"; ..... etc
```

because the [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17389/ysth) calls me a 'red hering' and I suppose it means I am not right, I will give you a [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) where you can read about that they also bring a example reading into this, they have column a INTEGER, and they say that

> if you omit the word OPTIONALLY, all fields are enclosed by the
>   ENCLOSED BY character.

and then they give the table:

```
CREATE TABLE jokes
  (a INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  joke TEXT NOT NULL);
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/jokes.txt' INTO TABLE jokes
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n%%\n' (joke);
```

and they say :

> If you specify OPTIONALLY, the ENCLOSED BY character is used only to
>   enclose values from columns that have a string data type (such as
>   CHAR, BINARY, TEXT, or ENUM):

```
1,"a string",100.20
2,"a string containing a , comma",102.20
3,"a string containing a " quote",102.20
4,"a string containing a ", quote and comma",102.20
```

I am no fish ! ;-)

Comment: So I must enclose the strings with double quote for `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY` to work? (asking this because it indeed does not work just adding it to the query, result doesn't change). If that's the case I'm not really sure how to go about that since the data is pretty dynamic and most fields rarely ever share the same length

Comment: yes you must enclose strings. and leave numeric data unenclosed, else all fields terminated by ; will be considered as enclosed by NOTHING, but enclosed and treated as strings. If you have enclosed and unenclosed fields it will consider the unenclosed as not strings. But you must specify the word optionally.

Comment: This seems likely to be a red herring.

Comment: what is a red hering ?

Comment: @MaxMuster A red herring is something that seems to be obvious what it is at first but after closer inspection turns out to be something completely different. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring.

Comment: I like fish :))

Comment: If you have further problems, please provide `SELECT HEX(col)...` for a sample of the messed up encoding.  That will help us debug it.

`UTF-16LE` is extremely rare; where is the data coming from?